# ViewPager showing duplicate views

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have encountered a problem in my Android application where the `ViewPager` is showing duplicate views.  I have two tabs, but both are showing the same thing.  Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            if (1==1) {
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Fragment fragment;
                    fragment = new BlankFragment();
                    return "Gas Prices".toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return "Map".toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            String latitude = intent.getStringExtra("lat");
            String longitude = intent.getStringExtra("long");
            textView.setText(latitude + "\n" + longitude);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I want `fragment_main.xml` to be the layout for the first tab and `map.xml` to be the layout for the second tab.

map.xml:

```
public class Map extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I have searched all over Google and SO for the answer, but nothing prevailed. I found a few answers, but it did not work for me because I have a `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SectionsPagerAdapter always creates the same kind of fragment. You should do something like this:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position+1);
            case 1:
                return new Map(); // 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Gas Prices".toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return "Map".toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using ViewModels within my ViewPager generated Fragment (which is using the same Fragment class). I was scoping my viewModel inside the ViewPagers fragment using [activityViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-apis). Of course in this situation the Activity was holding on to the previous fragments ViewModel instance thus leading to inconsistent behaviour when loading different Fragment instances of the same class type.
I fixed the issue using the viewModels scope instead:

```
val myFragment: MyFragment by viewModels()
```

Posting it here in case someone has the same problem as I did, took me a while to figure this one out..

My Adapter code:

```
class EpisodeSeriesAdapter(fragment: Fragment): 
FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
private var episodes: List<TmEpisodeAndStats> = emptyList()

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return episodes.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    val fragment = EpisodeDetailsFragment()
    val episodeDataModel = getEpisodeDataModelByNumber(position, episodes)

    fragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
        putParcelable(EpisodeDetailsFragment.EPISODE_DATA_KEY, episodeDataModel)
    }

    return fragment
}

fun updateEpisodes(episodes: List<TmEpisodeAndStats>) {
    this.episodes = episodes
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private fun getEpisodeDataModelByNumber(position: Int, episodes: List<TmEpisodeAndStats>): EpisodeDataModel {
    return EpisodeDataModel(
        episodes[position].episode.show_trakt_id,
        episodes[position].episode.episode_tmdb_id,
        episodes[position].episode.season_number ?: 0,
        episodes[position].episode.episode_number ?: 0,
        ""
    )
}
```

}